# Electric field inside a p-n junction

Tags: electric-fields, semiconductor-physics

In the diagram shown below it shows that as holes from p goes into n, it induces an electric field from n to p direction. Now i am not able to understand this correctly, the only reasons holes went towards the n direction is because of the attraction force caused by the electrons, hence shouldn'[image]t there also be an electric field from p to n direction? And the Net electric field should be the resultant of these both. Could someone explain to me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

*Basics*

Initially, at a metallurgical junction, there is a very large density gradient in both electron and hole concentrations. The majority of carrier electrons in the n region will begin diffusing into the p region and the majority of carrier holes in the p region will begin diffusing into the n region.

The diffusion process can not continue indefinitely. As electrons diffuse from the n region, positively charged donor atoms are left behind. Similarly, as holes diffuse from the p region, they uncover negatively charged acceptor atoms. The net positive and negative charges in the n and p regions induce an electric field in the region near the junction, in the direction from the positive to the negative charge, or from the n to the p region.

---

> In the diagram shown below shows that as holes from p go into n, it induces an electric field from n to p direction.

As we have seen from the basics, the induced electric field is due to both i.e. diffusion of holes and electrons.

> the only reason holes went towards the n direction is because of the attraction force caused by the electrons.

The reason for holes to diffuse towards n region is the concentration gradient. The same is applicable for electrons in n region.

> And the Net electric field should be the result of both.

Net induce field is due to both diffusions i.e. diffusion of an electron in the p region and holes in n region. The induced field produces by the acceptor and donor left behind.

Comment: I think part of OP's confusion is not realizing the semiconductor without any depletion region is charge neutral and therefore there is no field. You may consider stating this more directly. Also, it seems a bit weird to me to describe diffusion as "the reason for holes to attract toward n region". There isnt any attraction going on here.

Comment: Yes! you are right! The attraction might not be the right term to use. I'll edit. Thank you to point it out!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why electrons move from n to p and holes move from p to n is **not** that there is an electric field that draws them there.

The actual reason is that in thermodynamics, particles (for example electrons or holes, but also more generally, hydrogen molecules or diesel vapor) constantly move, and especially they move back and forth between two mutually connected vessels. In equilibrium, one does not normally notice that this happens because equal rates of particles move in the one and the other direction. But if, for example, in the one vessel there are no particles at all, it is very intuitively clear that particles can only move from the other vessel into the first. These will result in more an more particles accumulating in the formerly unoccupied vessel, until finally equilibrium is restored and again the same rate move from one to the other and back.

The apparent "force" that drives particles across the boundary to restore thermodynamic equilibrium is the so-called [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential) $\mu$, which is a function of the particle concentrations, among others. It shares some similarity with temperature. If temperature is equal between two systems, there is no heat flow. If chemical potential is equal between two systems, there is no diffusive particle flow.

So the reason for electrons moving to the p-region is simply that there is a lack of electrons in the p-region just after the pn-junction has been created. In other words, the chemical potential of electrons in the p-region is lower than in the n-region.

But contrary to an ordinary gas, where particles can diffuse to another vessel until the concentration is homogeneous in that vessel, charged particles are special in that they also create an electric potential difference as they get separated. This electric potential difference, which is initially zero (the p/n semiconductors are electrically neutral when the junction is formed) builds up until it perfectly counteracts the chemical potential difference, locally. This creates the depletion zone, a very short time after the n- and p-semiconductors have been welded together (or however diodes are manufactured...).

Since electrons are charged negative and move to the left (in your picture), while holes are kind of charged positive and move to the right, they both contribute in the same sense to the resulting electric potential in the depletion zone. Actually they don't add up, but they are two sides of the same coin because any electrical field is always directed from positive to negative charges, which, of course, requires the existence of both. So the final field in the depletion zone is the electric field from the positive atom bodies remaining in the n-region part of the depletion zone to the surplus electrons that have accumulated in the p-region part of the depletion zone.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is similar to what happens in some molecular bonds. In the water molecule for example, the electrons from the 2 hydrogen atoms are closer to the oxigen atom, forming a dipole. It happens due to the energy of atomic orbitals of each atom, what favors a migration from H to O.

In the p-n junction, band structures of the silicon crystals plays the role of atomic orbitals. Electrons form the n side migrate to p side decreasing the energy of the system. Even if this means creating a E-field in the region.